# How do I display category on a page separate from subcategory in Octobercms?

Tags: octobercms

Good day, I am new to Octobercms, trying to fix an issue. I have category and subcategory in my project, i have already implemented nested relationship for that and connected it to the product table via a pivot table. Right now when i drag the display list component and try to display the list of categories, it shows up with subcategories. I would love to have categories on one page connected to subcategories on another page. I don't really get how to use scope that shows up in the dropdown of the component. Any help to resolve this?

I have this as my scope but it doesnt seem to work

```
 public function scopeCategory($query)
{
    return $query->where('parent_id',0)


$cats = ::category()->parent_id()->orderBy('cat_title')->get();

};
```

i get this when i change the scope value

Illegal operator and value combination.

Comment: Sounds like a forum issue and not coding issue. Have you tried the manual or did you try to code a plugin??

Comment: Don't really get your question but i have looked up the documentation and i am building my plugin using builder. Just want to know if there is a piece of code to add to my model to filter categories alone instead of showing all the nested categories and subcategories from the database

Comment: Sounds definitely as forum question and not coding issue. This is a coding website where people help you out with coding issues.. not a fancy search engine for tutorials. Try one of the sister sites (e.g. Superusers).

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/sites#

Comment: I take it to mean you don't understand my question or how octobercms works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Osuji, you're asking for a step-through tutorial to accomplish something. That is not the core business of StackOverflow... therefore you have alternative sister sites. As explained to you its about  fixing code here due to hitting a bug or code that doesn't work. You provided neither of those two. I am, like many others, here to help you and not to pester you away. Therefore, I did link the overview of sister-sites where you can choose from. For example, migrate your question to https://superuser.com/ because you have much more luck there.... unless your "plug-in" for the too-be "website".

Comment: unless your "plug-in" for the too-be "website".. selfwritten or modified is not working. Then you should paste that scriptcode in your question. Only then its a valid question here and people are able to help you with your scriptcode.

Comment: I have been able resolve the problem by looking at laravel documentation maybe it is how i structured the question. I added the code i was asking for to my category model plugin and it worked. I added the solution to answers incase some other person needs clarification on that.

Comment: Cheers, now your question makes sense here at SO. Retracted "move flag". Gratz on the "I found myself a solution to my own question".

Comment: refer below link : https://octobercms.com/docs/api/october/rain/database/traits/nestedtree

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by adding this to my category model to show just categories with parent_id of 0

```
public function scopeCategory($query)
{
    return $query->where('parent_id', 0);
}
```